# Unity Emotiv in Rendered program

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I have created program with Unity 5.1.1f1 (32-bit) and made compability with Emotive EPOC headset. When i Start program from Unity editor, I can receive all the data from the headset. But when i render my program, I only get 0. I found out that you must manually add edk.dll and edk_utils.dll files into exported destination. But that didn't worked. Even tried launching program with Admin rights and different compability settings. I have read 2 pages of questions in this website, but couldn't find answer and I am out of ideas. If anyone can help, I would appreciate.

Comment: why not use the latest Unity?  there is no reason to not upgrade with Unity

Comment: But will it solve the problem? I read some forums and i have found out that    Emotiv EPOC doesn't work  with Unity 5+ versions. But that information is not 100% trusted and http://emotiv.com/support/ doesn't work for me.